# jQuery delegated change handler not working in Apps Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script, event-delegation

I'm trying to add a delegated change handler with jQuery in Google Apps script but it's not working.  I want to be able to have a user initiate the addition of a row to a table which contains a select box.

UPDATE: This is clearly an issue with Apps Script (maybe an issue with Caja sanitization?), as the code itself works in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jcarrano/bxkuvsyk/1/).  Does anyone have a suggestion for how I can achieve the same functionality that will work in GAS?

UPDATE2: I also tried using the older .delegate() method and that does not seem to work either.

```
<div class="outer">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Description</th><th>User Selection</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Pre Loaded</td>
      <td>
        <select>
          <option value="foo">foo</option>
          <option value="bar">bar</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button>Add New</button>
</div>
```

Script:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('button').click(function(){
     $('.outer table').append(
           "<tr>"
            +"<td>Post Loaded</td>"
            +"<td>"
              +"<select>"
                +"<option value=foo>foo</option>"
                +"<option value=bar>bar</option>"
              +"</select>"
            +"</td>"
          +"</tr>" 
      );
    });

    //delegate change handler
    $('.outer table').on('change', 'select', function() {
      alert($(this).val());
    })

    //direct change handler
//    $('.outer table select').on('change', function() {
//      alert($(this).val());
//    })
</script>
```